# XPathNavigator.SetValue Throws NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio-2005, xpath

I have the following code, whose last line results in a NotSupportedException on every execution, and I haven't found a way around it. This hypothetical analogous code finds a "book" with a specific title, with the goal of updating it to the new title. It does find the correct node, but fails to update it.

```
XPathDocument xpathDoc = new XPathDocument( fileName );
XPathNavigator nav = xpathDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNavigator node = nav.SelectSingleNode( @"//Book[Title='OldTitle']/Title" );

node.SetValue( "NewTitle" );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`XPathNavigator` objects created by `XPathDocument` objects are read-only (see [MSDN: Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx))
It should be created with `XmlDocument` to be editable:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(fileName);
XPathNavigator nav = xmlDoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNavigator node = nav.SelectSingleNode(@"//Book[Title='OldTitle']/Title");

node.SetValue("NewTitle");
```

Comment: But how can I use an XPath expression to find a node from an XMLDocument?

Comment: Never mind, it's the same CreateNavigator() method. I didn't notice that before. Awesome, thanks!